# How do you query a CouchDB view that emits complex keys?

Tags: couchdb

Given a CouchDB view that emits keys of the following format:

```
[ "part1", { "property": "part2" } ]
```

How can you find all documents with a given value for `part1`?

If `part2` was a simple string rather than an object `startkey=["part1"]&endkey=["part1",{}]` would work. The [CouchDB docs](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Complex_keys) state the following:

> The query `startkey=["foo"]&endkey=["foo",{}]` will match most array keys with "foo" in the first element, such as `["foo","bar"]` and `["foo",["bar","baz"]]`. However it will not match `["foo",{"an":"object"}]`

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't offer any suggestion on how to deal with such keys.

Answer (score 2):

The second element of your `endkey` value needs to be an object that collates after any possible value of the second element of your key.  Objects are compared by property-by-property (for example, `{"a":1}` < `{"a":2}` < `{"b":1}`) so the best way to do this is to set the first property name in your `endkey` to a very large value:

```
startkey=["part1"]&endkey=["part1", { "\uFFF0": false }]
```

The property name of `\uFFF0` should collate after any other property names in the second key element, and even works when the second element is an empty object or has more than one property.